Manga where the main character leaves the Hero group and tried to live a normal life
I am looking for the title of a manga where the main character (MC) is weak in the Hero group and he learns it in the dungeon. Then he asks to resign and the Hero accepted the request. After that tried to calculate on leave with one of the female team. Previously he is the founder group with the hero, and buy analysis eye he found friend and made the group big as today.
Not like other manga, where the MC resigned in disgrace. The Hero gives on leave payment to him. I don't know if the manga is updated because the story kinda like conflict, which not anyone likes this theme.

Banished From The Hero's Party hits a lot of those points

Do you remember anything that happens after he leaves the party? Does he succeed in having a normal life, and if so, what did he do for work? If the Hero gave him money, was he generally nice and respectful? Or did he just throw it on the ground and tell the guy to get lost? Can you clarify/reword some of the statements, specifically "After that tried to calculate on leave with one of the female team" (do you mean calculate his severance pay?) and "and buy analysis eye he found friend and made the group big as today"?

I remember he is going to new place. And having good life there. Since Banish always give negative vibe, I prefer resign or something related. Thank for everyone mention my error on the topic

Rather than editing the answer into your question, you should post it as an actual answer using the 'Your Answer' field below. That's the correct way to post an answer on this site, and you're more likely to earn additional reputation that way. If you don't post a proper answer, someone else probably will, but it might as well be you, since you found it.

As suggested in a comment, the question has a number of matches with Banished from the Hero's Party. This is available in many formats including Manga and Anime.
The main character is essentially the traditional early story mentor in a video game. When the hero is starting their journey this character seems strong and undefeatable, but as the party levels up their strength does not increase proportionately until they are left the weakest member of the team.
In Banished from the Hero's Party, this is the point the protagonist is, well... banished from the Hero's party.

That is, until one day, Ares, the Party's second-in-command, considers him a dead weight to the party members and banishes him from the group. Gideon heeds Ares' words and leaves without telling Ruti.
Hoping to live an easy life on the frontier, Gideon moves to a borderland town and opens an apothecary, changing his name to Red. However, keeping his former status a secret may not be as simple as he thinks, especially when Rit, a beautiful young adventurer and his previous crush, shows up and asks to move in with him!

